# Getting SSLPeerUnverifiedException on Twilio API calls

Tags: java, twilio, sslhandshakeexception

We are using twilio-java-sdk-3.4.1 since last 3 years. It was working fine until 31 May. Since then we are getting following exception for all USA numbers. Did any change happen on Twilio end during that time? We are using java 8.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:443)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:587)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:564)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.SmsList.create(SmsList.java:70)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:200)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:770)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:577)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:416)
```

Comment: Have you checked the expiration date of your SSL certificate?

Comment: Expiry date is correct. It's September 16, 2016

Comment: Something changed, did you check the host name you are connecting to and see if that's listed in the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio root certificate was upgraded.
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/twilio-api-certificate-update-on-may-31-2016